# Heart Rate Versus Respiratory Rate

Tags: sports, heart-rate

There are times when my respiratory rate increases more than my heart rate.  If running or cycling at a stead state (flat terrain, constant speed), heart rate and respiratory reach some steady state.   Then I start up a hill or run/cycle a sprint (say over several minutes), my breathing greatly increases but my heart doesn't change all that much.

At other times when climbing a long hill at a steady state over a period of time (say 30 - 60 minutes), my heart rate can get fairly high but I'm not breathing that hard.

Without commenting on my personal situation, what I'm trying to understand what is the normal relationship between heart rate vs respiratory rate in the human body during exercise?  I'm guessing that what I'm noticing is just anaerobic exercise?  What is the physiology of this relationship?

Comment: Your question is not really on topic for fitness, so I've edited it to make it clear that you are asking about the physiology behind the heart rate/respiratory rate connection, rather than a personal health question.